# Xenmobile IOS wrapping

Tags: ios, xcode, citrix

I'm Trying to wrap a very simple Objective-C app all it does is display the Username to the screen if it's inside Citrix managed space otherwise it should write that it's not inside Citrix managed space.

However when I try to wrap it after Exporting the IPA file from Xcode. then I try to wrap that IPA file with the MDX toolkit. and this is what happens..
I have no Idea what to do to make this work ? I do not believe I've done any wrapping before this point. and I've just followed a tutorial from Citrix on youtube the newest one I could find.

it's called "Tutorial - Develop with Citrix WorxSDK part 1"

**Edit**

forgot to mention I'm using 
Xcode 8.2.1
MDX toolkit 10.4.10
Newest Java jdk I could pull

[image: Problem with Wrapping claiming that an SDK app is not supported]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. MDX 10.4.10 is in my setup trying to wrap at compile time as I didn't supply the script in build phases it didn't know how to create the mdx file. which resulted in simply creating only the IPA file. The script creates a MDX file that I then later can imbed the IPA file into. this is the script that soleved it all for me:

```
export APPTYPE="Enterprise"
export STOREURL="http://example.com"
export DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`
export POLICYFILE="/Path/to/Policyfile.xml"
/Applications/Citrix/MDXToolkit/CGAppCLPrepTool SdkPrep -in "${CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH}" -out "/Users/Udvikling/Documents/Debug Builds/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_${DATE}.mdx" -storeUrl "${STOREURL}" -appIdPrefix "ABCDEFGH"  -policyXML "${POLICYFILE}" -appType "${APPTYPE}" -entitlements "${CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS}"
```